# How to fix "The wagon you are using has not implemented getFileList()" error

Tags: java, maven, tycho, maven-wagon-plugin, wagon

I have a working tycho project using tycho v2.3.0 and I need to use upgrade it with latest version of tycho v3.0.3.
Once I compile the project using tycho v3.0.3 and maven compiler v3.9.0, I got the following error:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:2.0.2:download (...) on project tycho.update: Execution of goal org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:2.0.2:download failed: **The wagon you are using has not implemented getFileList()**

Any ideas?

The wagon-maven-plugin:v2.0.2 is the latest version available for this plugin.

Comment: Is it possible your problem (introduced by upgrading) is related to [this](https://github.com/mojohaus/wagon-maven-plugin/issues/54#issuecomment-1370539703)?